# Is it possible to make one method out of these three?

Tags: c#, code-duplication

I have these three methods

```
public static void HtmlEncodeUserDetails(ProfileEditViewModel profileEditViewModel)
{
    HtmlEncodeUserDetailsByViewModel(profileEditViewModel);
    HtmlEncodeUserDetailsByViewModel(profileEditViewModel.BusinessInfoVm);
    HtmlEncodeUserDetailsByViewModel(profileEditViewModel.AddressVm);
}

public static void HtmlEncodeUserDetails(BillingPageViewModel billingPageViewModel)
{
    HtmlEncodeUserDetailsByViewModel(billingPageViewModel);
    HtmlEncodeUserDetailsByViewModel(billingPageViewModel.BusinessInfoVm);
    HtmlEncodeUserDetailsByViewModel(billingPageViewModel.AddressVm);
}

public static void HtmlEncodeUserDetails(OfflineSaleViewModel offlineSaleViewModel)
{
    HtmlEncodeUserDetailsByViewModel(offlineSaleViewModel);
    HtmlEncodeUserDetailsByViewModel(offlineSaleViewModel.BusinessInfoVm);
    HtmlEncodeUserDetailsByViewModel(offlineSaleViewModel.AddressVm);
}
```

Is there a way to make one rather than three without creating a new View Model?

Comment: If these three classes all descend from a common base class - sure, easy - just use the base class as the parameter for the method

Comment: Extract `BusinessInfoVm` and `AddressVm` into an Interface, then let the three models implement it. As for the model itself, it depends on what `HtmlEncodeUserDetailsByViewModel` accepts.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was hoping for some magic that I do not know but extracting to a new interface would require too many changes all over the project so I'll just keep it this way.

Comment: There are multiple ways to unify them with one method: as mentioned, use a base class, or add an interface, or use a marker interface, or use generics etc.  But before I unify them into a single method, I would first ask what is the purpose of making them into one method?  Are these related ViewModels?  What is the signature of HtmlEncodeUserDetailsByViewModel method?  Does it have three overloads?  Is the implementation of that method under your control etc.

Comment: *"extracting to a new interface would require too many changes all over the project"*. No it wouldn't. It would require that you define the interface and then declare each of those three models as implementing it. That's all that would be required because nowhere else that uses these types needs to know or care about that interface. The classes are still what they are so can continue to be used as such everywhere but for the united method in this case.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The first view model is already inheriting from another view model and multiple inheritance is not supported.

Comment: @sonny-n That method expects a <T>; the purpose is to avoid code duplication, it was just a quick check, either you guys or ChatGPT : D

Comment: @EmilijaVilijaTrečiokaitė - _"multiple inheritance is not supported."_ - you can implement as many interfaces as you need. Multiple inheritance refers to inheriting actual classes, not interfaces.

Comment: _"either you guys or ChatGPT"_ - Mind that ChatGPT does _not know how to program_, actually.

Answer (score 2):

What do all three model-classes have in common? That should be an interface. For example:

```
public interface IHtmlEncodableViewModel
{
    IHtmlEncodableViewModel BusinessInfoVm {get; set;}
    IHtmlEncodableViewModel AddressVm {get; set;}
}

public class ProfileEditViewModel: IHtmlEncodableViewModel
{
    IHtmlEncodableViewModel BusinessInfoVm {get; set;}
    IHtmlEncodableViewModel AddressVm {get; set;}
}

public class BillingPageViewModel: IHtmlEncodableViewModel
{
    IHtmlEncodableViewModel BusinessInfoVm {get; set;}
    IHtmlEncodableViewModel AddressVm {get; set;}
}

public class OfflineSaleViewModel: IHtmlEncodableViewModel
{
    IHtmlEncodableViewModel BusinessInfoVm {get; set;}
    IHtmlEncodableViewModel AddressVm {get; set;}
}

public static void HtmlEncodeUserDetails(IHtmlEncodableViewModel viewModel)
{
    HtmlEncodeUserDetailsByViewModel(viewModel);
    HtmlEncodeUserDetailsByViewModel(viewModel.BusinessInfoVm);
    HtmlEncodeUserDetailsByViewModel(viewModel.AddressVm);
}

public static void HtmlEncodeUserDetailsByViewModel(IHtmlEncodableViewModel viewModel)
{
    // process
}
```